# Filling array with listbox multiple selected items

Tags: arrays, excel, ms-access, vba

I am sharing my code because other code found online either does not work because it was created for excel and not access, as syntax is a little different, or is missing the key function needed, that being based off multi selection.

**That said... this code does the following:**

having a list box that's row source is query results the code simply puts multiple selected items from a list box in an array to be used in later code.

The difference from excel to access is `.list` works in excel while `.Column(0, i)` works in access

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Variant
Dim MultiArr()

If Me.lbMultiEdit.ListIndex <> -1 Then
    For i = 0 To Me.lbMultiEdit.ListCount - 1
        If Me.lbMultiEdit.Selected(i) Then
            ReDim Preserve MultiArr(x)
            MultiArr(x) = Me.lbMultiEdit.Column(0, i)
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next i
End If

'sanity check....
For i = 0 To x - 1
    MsgBox MultiArr(i)
Next i
```

Comment: Please delete the answer and edit your question to include the code. Otherwise the answer will be deleted ... because it's not an answer... and we will have no code!

Comment: did, thanks for the input

Answer (score 1):

Your code is non-optimized. It resizes the array for every item that's added. A `ReDim Preserve` is a very intensive operation, because it essentially creates a new array of the desired size, and then moves all items over.

A more optimized variant, that never uses `ReDim Preserve`:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Variant
Dim MultiArr()

If Me.lbMultiEdit.ItemsSelected.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub 'No items selected
ReDim MultiArr(0 To Me.lbMultiEdit.ItemsSelected.Count - 1)

If Me.lbMultiEdit.ListIndex <> -1 Then 'Why?
    For i = 0 To Me.lbMultiEdit.ListCount - 1
        If Me.lbMultiEdit.Selected(i) Then
            MultiArr(x) = Me.lbMultiEdit.Column(0, i)
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next i
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than iterating over all items and testing whether each item is selected, you could merely iterate over only the selected items, for example:

```
Dim i As Integer, v, MultiArr()
ReDim MultiArr(0 To Me.lbMultiEdit.ItemsSelected.Count - 1)

For Each v In Me.lbMultiEdit.ItemsSelected
    MultiArr(i) = Me.lbMultiEdit.ItemData(v)
    i = 1 + i
Next v
```

Or, using a `With` statement:

```
Dim i As Integer, v, MultiArr()

With Me.lbMultiEdit
    ReDim MultiArr(0 To .ItemsSelected.Count - 1)
    For Each v In .ItemsSelected
        MultiArr(i) = .ItemData(v)
        i = 1 + i
    Next v
End With
```